# URL encode GAE query string using Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib, url-encoding

I am programming a online Expression Calculator in GAE using Python. I am using query string to get the query and then evaluate the expression. For example for `ishamsample.appspot.com/eval?q=9-6` browser should show `{9-3}{6}` This like query is working properly but the problem is + symbol. `ishamsample.appspot.com/eval?q=1+6` Below is my code. I tried URL quoting

```
class Eval(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        q=self.request.get('q')
        q=urllib.quote(q)
        code=eval(compile(q,'<string>', 'eval', __future__.division.compiler_flag))
        self.response.write('{'+q+'}{'+str(code)+'}')
```

For that browser shows output as `{1%206}{1}`
[image]

How to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should not encode** the string you get as GET parameter on the server side. You should be decoding it; and GAE does that for you. Whoever is the client (here: you as a user) should encode the symbols before making an HTTP request.

Your request should look like:

```
http://.../?q=1%2B6
```

---

One comment that I cant resist making: **EVAL IS EVIL**. Please refer to a [similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) on how to do it using `ast.literal_eval(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

- is a special symbol, it is supposed to replace spaces. In the url you should have %2B. If you post the query from a text input it should be encoded naturally. Nothing to do with python or GAE

Comment: Nope in URL, users put + sign and thats why I need URL Encoding here. For example, if a user put `ishamsample.appspot.com/eval?q=1+6 ` it should encode `+` to `%2B` and give result as `{1+6}{7}`. Most of the users dont know the URL value for + thus we have to encode it.

Comment: @IshamMohamed He is actually correct in what he is saying. So a +1 from my side.